# Can Word change the format of embedded images in a docx file?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office, microsoft-word-2010, docx

I've got a Word document that's massively bloated due to some images embedded in the document being saved as 5-40 MB emf files instead of a jpg that takes up .1% of the size. Does Word have any built in utility for changing image formats document-wide or am I stuck with editing the docx by hand?

Comment: Why not use image compression document-wide? FWIW, I've done the manual route on a 200-page document and it took less time than I thought it would.

Comment: Image compression document-wide? What do you mean by that? Isn't everyrthing automatically compressed when it goes into the .zip docx container? Though, I'm actually finished with the reencoding (search & replace .emf with .jpeg on the resource XML, suck out the emfs, shove them through imagemagik, push them back in.) so yeah, it's easier than I thought. Still, I'd like it if Word could handle this automatically.